# Calculate year end column total

Tags: sql, sas

I have a dataset in SAS which has columns as follows:

Date: format of this field is '15Dec2014' 
Amount: e.g. 20000

I need to calculate year end sum totals. so for a particular year, the total of Amount at 31Dec2014. I eventually want to store each year end totals in a separate dataset. Any ideas?

Comment: This is not a code writing service, please post what you've tried. This is a PROC MEANS or PROC SQL that should be straightforward, try googling "SAS summary statistics"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
/*For each date in a year, 'INTNX' will give you the year end date*/

Data answer;
set your_sas_dataset;
year_end=put(intnx('year ', Date , 0, 'e'),date9.);
run;

/*Summing amount on the year end dates will give us the totals for a particular year as of 31st December*/

Proc sql;
Select year_end, sum(Amount) as year_end_totals
from
answer
group by year_end;
quit;
```

Hope this helps:-)